Probability of Seeing All Original Balls in Polya's Urn?
Here is a variation of Polya-Urn (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model) and the Coupon Collector Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) I thought of.

Suppose there is a hat with 3 Red Balls and 3 Blue Balls (RB_1, RB_2, RB_3, BB_1, BB_2, BB_3)
RB = Red Ball, BB = Blue Ball
Each ball has the same probability of being selected
Randomly pick a ball - put it back along with another ball of the same color (e.g. RB_4, BB_4)
Repeat this process again

Based on this, I have the following questions:

Question 1: Suppose $n$ iterations have passed and you have seen $k$ of the 6 original balls at least once ($k<6$). How many more iterations are needed such that each of the 6 balls are seen at least once?
Question 2: Suppose $n$ iterations have passed and you have seen  $k$ of the 6 original balls at least once  ($k<6$). What is the probability that after $j$ more iterations, you will have seen each of the 6 original balls at least once?
Question 3: Probabilistically, is there a "point of no return"? The more iterations that go by, the odds of seeing any of the original balls reduces. Is there some "breaking point", i.e. after $n$ turns if you have not seen each of the original balls at least once - there is now virtually no chance? Does such an $n$ exist?

To get started, I tried to simulate this in experiment 1000 times in R (i.e. Game 1: 1000 iterations, Game 2: 1000 iterations ....., Game 999: 1000 iterations, Game 1000: 1000 iterations):

Now, I am trying to approach this problem mathematically.
Recently I learned that the "long term distribution" of Polya's Urn follows a Beta Distribution (Polya's urn model - limit distribution). I think this fact will be useful.
I have started working on some analysis and will post my progress as I go.
Thanks for the support everyone!

Note: I can share the R code if anyone is interested


The answer to Question 3 is no - there is no breaking point.  If there are $n$ balls at some stage, the probability of not seeing a particular ball in the next $d$ draws is $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+2}\cdots\frac{n+d-2}{n+d-1} $ $= \frac{n-1}{n+d-1} \to 0$ as $d$ increases.

Incidentally, none of your questions seem to be affected by the colours of the balls.

Do you start with $k$ original balls or with $6$ original balls?

@ Henry: Thank you so much for your comments!

We start with $i=6$ original balls. At time $t=1,2,3\ldots$ the probability of selecting
one of the original balls is $i/(i-1+t)$; the number of balls in the urn
(original plus added) is $i-1+t$ before the $t$-th selection and $i+t$ after the $t$-th selection.
If the probability of having seen $k\ge 0$ of the original balls
after pick $t$ is denoted by $P_{t,k}$, the branching in the tree of all possible experiments
is
$$
P_{t,k} = P_{t-1,k-1}\frac{i}{i-1+t}+P_{t-1,k}(1-\frac{i}{i-1+t}).
$$
It's easy to build a full table with this recurrence numerically.
The initial values are $P_{0,0}=1$, $P_{0,k\neq 1}=0$.
In the spirit of the coupon collector problem, the question targets having seen $k$ distinct
of the original balls, $1\le k\le i$. [One could perhaps run an inclusion-exclusion filter across the aforementioned $P$.]
We regard the number of original balls that appear repeatedly as members of
the non-interesting set. So the recurrence is modified to a less favorable branching ratio to
select one more ball not out of $i$ but out of $i-(k-1)$ if already $k-1$ distinct of
the original balls have been picked:
$$
P_{t,k} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
P_{t-1,k-1}\frac{i-(k-1)}{i-1+t}+P_{t-1,k}(1-\frac{i-k}{i-1+t}),& i-(k-1)\ge 0; \\
P_{t-1,k},& i-(k-1)< 0.\\
\end{array}
\right .
$$
The time development is for $i=6$ like this:
t=1 k=1 P=1 = 1.00000
t=1 k=2 P=0 = 0.00000
t=1 k=3 P=0 = 0.00000
t=1 k=4 P=0 = 0.00000
t=1 k=5 P=0 = 0.00000
t=1 k=6 P=0 = 0.00000

t=2 k=1 P=2/7 = 0.28571
t=2 k=2 P=5/7 = 0.71429
t=2 k=3 P=0 = 0.00000
t=2 k=4 P=0 = 0.00000
t=2 k=5 P=0 = 0.00000
t=2 k=6 P=0 = 0.00000

t=3 k=1 P=3/28 = 0.10714
t=3 k=2 P=15/28 = 0.53571
t=3 k=3 P=5/14 = 0.35714
t=3 k=4 P=0 = 0.00000
t=3 k=5 P=0 = 0.00000
t=3 k=6 P=0 = 0.00000

t=4 k=1 P=1/21 = 0.04762
t=4 k=2 P=5/14 = 0.35714
t=4 k=3 P=10/21 = 0.47619
t=4 k=4 P=5/42 = 0.11905
t=4 k=5 P=0 = 0.00000
t=4 k=6 P=0 = 0.00000

t=3800 k=1 P=2/2209677920472337 = 0.00000
t=3800 k=2 P=18995/2209677920472337 = 0.00000
t=3800 k=3 P=48095340/2209677920472337 = 0.00000
t=3800 k=4 P=45654501495/2209677920472337 = 0.00002
t=3800 k=5 P=17330448767502/2209677920472337 = 0.00784
t=3800 k=6 P=2192301769089003/2209677920472337 = 0.99214

t=5000 k=1 P=2/8706626751739917 = 0.00000
t=5000 k=2 P=24995/8706626751739917 = 0.00000
t=5000 k=3 P=11897620/1243803821677131 = 0.00000
t=5000 k=4 P=14863101785/1243803821677131 = 0.00001
t=5000 k=5 P=7425605651786/1243803821677131 = 0.00597
t=5000 k=6 P=412121113674123/414601273892377 = 0.99402

The expectation values for the times of having picked $k$ distinct original balls are $E_k=\sum_t tP_{t,k}$.
Summing over the first $t\le 80$ these partial sums are:
k= 1 E=2.49960
k= 2 E=12.37798
k= 3 E=61.62654
k= 4 E=312.69547
k= 5 E=1116.35886
k= 6 E=1734.44155

Summing over the $t\le 160$ of these partial sums give:
k= 1 E=2.49995
k= 2 E=12.46728
k= 3 E=67.92520
k= 4 E=484.55048
k= 5 E=3054.32631
k= 6 E=9258.23077

Summing over the $t\le 1000$ of these partial sums give:
k= 1 E=2.50000
k= 2 E=12.49911
k= 3 E=73.81131
k= 4 E=1001.90220
k= 5 E=26931.19683
k= 6 E=472478.09050

Numerically this looks like conjectured expectation times of $2.5$, $12.5$, $75?$...
(I have no formal proof of that, only lower limits. I did not try to speed up convergence with any type of Levin/Wynn-algorithm.)
The question 1 "how many more iterations are needed.."  sound like that is what was asked (??).
Of course, an infinity of more iterations are needed to ensure (!) that each
of the remaining $i-k$ balls are also at least once.
Maple program:
# probability of having seen k distinct original balls
# starting from i original balls after step t.
P := proc(i,k,t)
    option remember;
    if t=0 then
        if k=0 then
            1;
        else
            0 ;
        end if
    else
        if i-(k-1) >= 0 then
            procname(i,k-1,t-1)*(i-k+1)+procname(i,k,t-1)*(t+k-1) ;
            %/(i-1+t) ;
        else
            procname(i,k,t-1) ;
        end if;
    end if;
end proc:
i := 6 ;
# cp are the sum of the probabilities (expectation values....)
cp := [seq(0,k=1..i)] ;
# loop over the time steps
for t from 1 do
    for k from 1 to i do
        p := P(i,k,t) ;
        if t < 30 or modp(t,200)=0 then
            printf("t=%d k=%d P=%a = %.5f\n",t,k,p,evalf(p)) ;
        end if;
        pold := op(k,cp) ;
        # compute expectatino value by adding time times probability
        cp := subsop(k=pold+t*p,cp) ;
    end do:
    if t < 30 or modp(t,200)=0 then
        for k from 1 to i do
            printf("k= %d E=%.5f\n",k,evalf(op(k,cp))) ;
        end do:
    end if;
end do:

About Question 2: If already $\hat k$ of the original balls have been selected (coupon collector, each at least one) after $n$ picks,
what is the probability of collection the other $i-\hat k$ at some time in the future?
The answer to this is given by restarting the experiment with $i+n$ in total and calculating
the requested $P^{(2)}_{j,i}$ with the equivalent algorithm:
$$
P^{(2)}_{j,k} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
P^{(2)}_{j-1,k-1}\frac{i-(k-1)}{n+i-1+j}+P^{(2)}_{j-1,k}(1-\frac{i-k}{n+i-1+j}),& i-(k-1)\ge 0; \\
P^{(2)}_{j-1,k},& i-(k-1)< 0.\\
\end{array}
\right .
$$
starting at $P^{(2)}_{0,k=\hat k}=1$, $P^{(2)}_{0,k\neq \hat k}=0$.
